Ghusl and ingrown toenails
Both of my toes have mild ingrown toenails as the nails are curved but they don't penetrate the flesh. However, when doing ghusl or wudu water does not reach those parts of the skin covered by the curved nails. What should I do? I've tried to make sure that water reaches those parts but I remain uncertain.
Have my ghusl and wudu (and ultimately salat) been invalid? I've been thinking of going to a doctor to remove the nails once and for all.

If washing there causes unbearable hardship for you, it is not necessary to wash there based on the Unbearable Hardship principle.
Allah clearly states in Qur'an that:

'He does not burden any beyond their capacities' (2:286)

Reference
